# set_time_limit не увеличивается

Tags: php

Здравствуйте . 
Если поставить  в файле set_time_limit равный 5 секундам - все окей. А вот если ставлю неограниченно или 500 и более, то скрипт выполняется ровно 120 сек.

Где вносить правки (ВДС)? 
Спасибо

Comment: max_execution_time  в phpinfo равно 30

Comment: единственное значение в phpinfo, равное 120, - это `realpath_cache_ttl`